# writing data to text file and then trying to read the data from the text file shows stream not readable

Tags: vb.net

I have created a form to write data to a text file and to read the data from the text file. The program is working fine, if I run the program and write data to text file. The data is saved to the file. Then I stop the program and re-run it and now read the data from the file, the text data is also shown in the corresponding text box.

But the problem occurs when I write the data to the text file and then try to read the data from the text file without re-running the program. Now in this case, it shows error: `Stream was not readable.`

Why is it so?

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim fileStream_ As FileStream
    Dim fileWrite_ As StreamWriter
    Dim fileRead_ As StreamReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            fileStream_ = New FileStream("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
    ' for WRITE data to text file
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            fileWrite_ = New StreamWriter(fileStream_)
            fileWrite_.Write(TextBox1.Text)
            fileWrite_.Close()
            MsgBox("Text written to file", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
    ' for READ data from text file
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            fileRead_ = New StreamReader(fileStream_)
            TextBox2.Text = fileRead_.ReadToEnd
            fileRead_.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: But I really suggest you to rewrite this code and get rid of all those unneeded global variables

Comment: `Just closing the file is not enough to relinquis all the unmanaged resources.` why isn't it, close calls the `Dispose` method. OP take Steve's advice above about the vars, specifically the `fileStream_` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not keep these global variables around because you don't really need them.
And they can shoot in your feet when, for some reason they are no more valid.

Yours is an example case where global variables introduce subtle and not evident bugs. When you close the StreamWriter the **fileStream_** variable is automatically disposed and, in the next button click, is no more usable.
Of course if you close/reopen the application and go directly to read the file, it works. But then, it will be the write that will fail.

Instead use the [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement?msclkid=b5bf855aab8811ecaaf9fccb0bab1968) to correctly handle all disposable objects like a StreamWriter, StreamReader or FileStream

So your click handlers could be rewritten as

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using fileStream_ As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Using fileWrite_ As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileStream_)
                fileWrite_.Write(TextBox1.Text)
                ' the call to close is no more needed when inside the using
                ' fileWrite_.Close() 
                MsgBox("Text written to file", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox2.Text = ""
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Using fileStream_ As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Using fileRead_ As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileStream_)
                TextBox2.Text = fileRead_.ReadToEnd
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But, unless you have some valid reasons for these Streams to exist, then you can code everything with a single statement.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt", TextBox1.Text)
        MsgBox("Text written to file", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
       TextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The [File class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?msclkid=0971d482ab8911ec8d420fd791bd7280&view=net-6.0) has many useful methods when you need to work with files

Answer (score 1):

While you close the writer, the underlying steam also gets closed, you need to  create a new instance of the stream if you need to read from the same file.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.close?view=net-6.0

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim fileStream_ As FileStream
Dim fileWrite_ As StreamWriter
Dim fileRead_ As StreamReader

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
End Sub
' for WRITE data to text file
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        fileStream_ = New FileStream("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        fileWrite_ = New StreamWriter(fileStream_)
        fileWrite_.Write(TextBox1.Text)
        fileWrite_.Close()
        MsgBox("Text written to file", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
' for READ data from text file
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        fileStream_ = New FileStream("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\demo\vb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read)
        fileRead_ = New StreamReader(fileStream_)
        TextBox2.Text = fileRead_.ReadToEnd
        fileRead_.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

I would also suggest you to wrap the stream using 'Using' statement in order to better manage the resource

Comment: Of course, `Using` would be preferable. But your answer can be improved by adding a `Finally` clause to your `Try/Catch` blocks to always clean up the disposable objects, even in the event of an exception.